# procedurally generate a sphere mesh

Tags: 3d, mesh

i am looking for an algorithm ( in pseudo code) that generates the 3d coordinates of a sphere mesh like this:

[image]

the number of horizontal and lateral slices should be configurable

Comment: no, it's not. it's for a personal project.

Comment: that's called a disco ball configuration of points on a sphere as far as i know. its the easiest configuration.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If there are M lines of latitude (horizontal) and N lines of longitude (vertical), then put dots at

(x, y, z) = (sin(Pi * m/M) cos(2Pi * n/N), sin(Pi * m/M) sin(2Pi * n/N), cos(Pi * m/M))

for each m in { 0, ..., M } and n in { 0, ..., N-1 } and draw the line segments between the dots, accordingly.

edit: maybe adjust M by 1 or 2 as required, because you should decide whether or not to count "latitude lines" at the poles

Comment: +1, because this works with any graphics library. Another Question: Is there a way to also control the radius of the sphere?

Comment: @kiltek : this gives values for (x, y, z) from 0 to 1. To scale it to any radius, just multiply each point by your desired radius.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, you can use [meshzoo](https://github.com/nschloe/meshzoo#sphere-surface) (a project of mine) to generate meshes on spheres very easily.

You can optionally use [optimesh](https://github.com/nschloe/optimesh) (another one out of my stash) to optimize even further.

```py
import meshzoo
import optimesh

points, cells = meshzoo.icosa_sphere(10)


class Sphere:
    def f(self, x):
        return (x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2 + x[2] ** 2) - 1.0

    def grad(self, x):
        return 2 * x

points, cells = optimesh.cvt.quasi_newton_uniform_full(
    points, cells, 1.0e-2, 100, verbose=False,
    implicit_surface=Sphere(),
    # step_filename_format="out{:03d}.vtk"
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is just off the top of my head without testing. It could be a good starting point.

This will give you the most accurate and customizable results with the most degree of precision if you use double.

```
public void generateSphere(3DPoint center, 3DPoint northPoint
                          , int longNum, int latNum){

     // Find radius using simple length equation
        (distance between center and northPoint)

     // Find southPoint using radius.

     // Cut the line segment from northPoint to southPoint
        into the latitudinal number

     // These will be the number of horizontal slices (ie. equator)

     // Then divide 360 degrees by the longitudinal number
        to find the number of vertical slices.

     // Use trigonometry to determine the angle and then the
        circumference point for each circle starting from the top.

    // Stores these points in however format you want
       and return the data structure. 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a working C# code for the above answer:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter), typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class ProcSphere : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Mesh mesh;
    private Vector3[] vertices;

    public int horizontalLines, verticalLines;
    public int radius;

    private void Awake()
    {
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.name = "sphere";
        vertices = new Vector3[horizontalLines * verticalLines];
        int index = 0;
        for (int m = 0; m < horizontalLines; m++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < verticalLines - 1; n++)
            {
                float x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI * m/horizontalLines) * Mathf.Cos(2 * Mathf.PI * n/verticalLines);
                float y = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI * m/horizontalLines) * Mathf.Sin(2 * Mathf.PI * n/verticalLines);
                float z = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.PI * m / horizontalLines);
                vertices[index++] = new Vector3(x, y, z) * radius;
            }
        }
        mesh.vertices = vertices;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (vertices == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++) {
            Gizmos.color = Color.black;
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.TransformPoint(vertices[i]), 0.1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested this in Unity and it worked. But my edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24704133 got rejected. Why? @yshahak can you add my changes?

Answer (score 1):

just a guess, you could probably use the formula for a sphere centered at (0,0,0)

```
x²+y²+z²=1
```

solve this for x, then loop throuh a set of values for y and z and plot them with your calculated x.

Comment: Not sure this is a good idea, depending on the performance requirements of the project in question, as this method surely involves a `sqrt()`, which I believe is expensive.

Comment: If anyone decided they actually wanted to try this method, they would probably also need to be directed to an article on [Marching Cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes)...