# Drawing 3D sphere in C/C++

Tags: c, graphics, voxel

I am looking for an algorithm which can draw a nice looking 3D sphere on small resolution. I found [Bresenham's circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) but it's for 2D drawing. I just need spheres borders (I don't need it filled). I also googled for a solution of the problem but I didn't find anything. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084189/draw-a-sphere-using-3d-pixels-voxels) article doesn't help (what is the brute force algorithm?). I can't use any OpenGL libraries, I need vanilla C/C++ solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid that your stated problem has no solution. C/C++ do not define standard graphics libraries. I'm also a little surprised that you haven't decided which language to use yet.

Comment: What's wrong with the circle drawing? The border of a 3D sphere IS a cricle.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am coding in C but there's not a big difference between both languages so even if someone shows code in C++ it won't be hard to be rewritten in C. Other languages are also accepted, I want to find out the idea!

Comment: You still don't seem to be acknowledging the impossibility of what you ask

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I will write it myself and prove u it's possible.

Comment: It's not possible to help some people. Here comes my downvote.

Comment: What you need is called a sphere tessellation algorithm, there are tons of tutorials for that out there. You can implement such an algorithm in a modeling program's scripting language; you don't need to draw anything at all.

Comment: @user1095108 Given that the stated aim of the question is to draw a sphere, I think your comment is a little hard to understand

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Read again, he asks for an algorithm that _can_ draw a sphere, not that he necessarily wants to draw the sphere himself.

Comment: @user1095108 OK. An algorithm that can draw is a bit of a non-sequitur, mind you.

Comment: @Ezio_ what is your imaging target device? LED cube? (filled or just surface with what organisation) or you rasterize to array or where ? also the resolution is pretty important. Add these specifications with an example how to render simple point in your platform so it is possible to answer (without this info you get down/close votes all the time)

Comment: Please stop ripping on this guy for for stating that he is looking for a library independent solution. Obviously what he means is that he is looking for a way to generate an array of voxels depicting the sphere the sphere without the use of a library so he can conceptualize the process and then implement it himself using a standard openGL library. So, please do not downvote this valid post just because it's creator didn't word his thoughts perfectly enough.

Answer (score 7):

if I get it right you want to render all surface Voxels of sphere

The brute force is `O(R^3)`. If you just project rays from plane and compute the 3-th coordinate then you get `O(R^2)` but to make sure that no **Voxels** are missing you have to do this projection from all 3 planes which is still `O(R^2)`

It look like this:

[image: sphere]

on LED cube `16x16x16` simulation. Now the algorithm:

1. **compute visible bounding box**

   no need to render whole rendering space just the sphere so center +/- radius...
2. **take one plane (XY for example)**

   Cast rays from all `x,y` points inside bounding box which is just 2 for loops and compute the `z` coordinates where the ray hits via sphere equation:

   ```
   (x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2 + (z-z0)^2 = R^2
   ```

   so

   ```
   z=z0 +/- sqrt(R^2 - (x-x0)^2 - (y-y0)^2)
   ```

   and render the two **voxels**. The `int sqrt(int x)` for limited size (like LED Cube/Screen or Voxel space) can be done via **LUT** lookup table to speed things up.
3. **do the step #2 for all planes (`xy,yz,xz`)**

The code in **C++** looks like this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- LED cube class ver: 1.00 ----------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _LED_cube_h
#define _LED_cube_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int _LED_cube_size=16;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class LED_cube
    {
public:
    int n,map[_LED_cube_size][_LED_cube_size][_LED_cube_size];

    LED_cube()              { n=_LED_cube_size; }
    LED_cube(LED_cube& a)   { *this=a; }
    ~LED_cube()             { }
    LED_cube* operator = (const LED_cube *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //LED_cube* operator = (const LED_cube &a) { /*...copy...*/ return this; }
    void cls(int col);                                  // clear cube with col 0x00BBGGRR
    void sphere(int x0,int y0,int z0,int r,int col);    // draws sphere surface with col 0x00BBGGRR
    void glDraw();                                      // render cube by OpenGL as 1x1x1 cube at 0,0,0
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void LED_cube::cls(int col)
    {
    int x,y,z;
    for (x=0;x<n;x++)
     for (y=0;y<n;y++)
      for (z=0;z<n;z++)
       map[x][y][z]=col;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void LED_cube::sphere(int x0,int y0,int z0,int r,int col)
    {
    int x,y,z,xa,ya,za,xb,yb,zb,xr,yr,zr,xx,yy,zz,rr=r*r;
    // bounding box
    xa=x0-r; if (xa<0) xa=0; xb=x0+r; if (xb>n) xb=n;
    ya=y0-r; if (ya<0) ya=0; yb=y0+r; if (yb>n) yb=n;
    za=z0-r; if (za<0) za=0; zb=z0+r; if (zb>n) zb=n;
    // project xy plane
    for (x=xa,xr=x-x0,xx=xr*xr;x<xb;x++,xr++,xx=xr*xr)
     for (y=ya,yr=y-y0,yy=yr*yr;y<yb;y++,yr++,yy=yr*yr)
        {
        zz=rr-xx-yy; if (zz<0) continue; zr=sqrt(zz);
        z=z0-zr; if ((z>0)&&(z<n)) map[x][y][z]=col;
        z=z0+zr; if ((z>0)&&(z<n)) map[x][y][z]=col;
        }
    // project xz plane
    for (x=xa,xr=x-x0,xx=xr*xr;x<xb;x++,xr++,xx=xr*xr)
     for (z=za,zr=z-z0,zz=zr*zr;z<zb;z++,zr++,zz=zr*zr)
        {
        yy=rr-xx-zz; if (yy<0) continue; yr=sqrt(yy);
        y=y0-yr; if ((y>0)&&(y<n)) map[x][y][z]=col;
        y=y0+yr; if ((y>0)&&(y<n)) map[x][y][z]=col;
        }
    // project yz plane
    for (y=ya,yr=y-y0,yy=yr*yr;y<yb;y++,yr++,yy=yr*yr)
     for (z=za,zr=z-z0,zz=zr*zr;z<zb;z++,zr++,zz=zr*zr)
        {
        xx=rr-zz-yy; if (xx<0) continue; xr=sqrt(xx);
        x=x0-xr; if ((x>0)&&(x<n)) map[x][y][z]=col;
        x=x0+xr; if ((x>0)&&(x<n)) map[x][y][z]=col;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void LED_cube::glDraw()
    {
    #ifdef __gl_h_
    int x,y,z;
    float p[3],dp=1.0/float(n-1);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE,GL_ONE);

    glPointSize(2.0);

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);

    for (p[0]=-0.5,x=0;x<n;x++,p[0]+=dp)
     for (p[1]=-0.5,y=0;y<n;y++,p[1]+=dp)
      for (p[2]=-0.5,z=0;z<n;z++,p[2]+=dp)
        {
        glColor4ubv((BYTE*)(&map[x][y][z]));
        glVertex3fv(p);
        }
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glPointSize(1.0);
    #endif
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

class usage:

```cpp
LED_cube cube;
cube.cls(0x00202020); // clear space to dark gray color
int a=cube.n>>1;      // just place sphere to middle and size almost the whole space
int r=a-3;
cube.sphere(a,a,a,r,0x00FFFFFF);
cube.glDraw();        // just for mine visualization you have to rewrite it to your rendering system
```

If you want to use **C** only then decompose class to just global functions and variables and translate **C++** operators `x++,--,+=,-=,*=,...` to **C** style `x=x+1,...`

Answer (score 5):

Based on the link, it looks like you're more interested in *voxel algorithms for spheres*, rather than *graphics* per se; say something like [this page](https://neil.fraser.name/news/2006/11/17/) helps with. You don't want a ball, but the surface only.

[Midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) can be used to draw 3D voxel spheres: consider the sphere as a stack of slices, and each slice contains a circle.

In practice, you use two nested midpoint circles, the outer defining the radius for the inner one. (Although a naive algorithm drawing circles on top of each other will likely leave holes in the voxels, the midpoint circle algorithm exploits symmetries, and if correctly implemented, no such holes should occur.)

You build six caps in tandem, like carving a cube into a sphere. Since the surface slopes on each cap are always less than 1, going outwards on a cap will at most change each coordinate by 1, so holes cannot occur.

The problem with this approach is the complexity: each point you calculate may affect up to 48 voxel cells. (At each cap, each point is calculated within an octant, and therefore affects eight cells. There are six caps, and 6*8=48.)

I suggest a different approach.

The equation for the surface of a *r*-radius sphere centered at *x<sub>0</sub>*, *y<sub>0</sub>*, *z<sub>0</sub>*, is

> (*x* - *x*<sub>0</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (*y* - *y*<sub>0</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (*z* - *z*<sub>0</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = *r*<sup>2</sup>

With integer coordinater, the grid points are rarely exactly on the sphere surface, allow a range of values:

> *RR<sub>MIN</sub>* ≤ (*x* - *x*<sub>0</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (*y* - *y*<sub>0</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (*z* - *z*<sub>0</sub>)<sup>2</sup> ≤ *RR<sub>MAX</sub>*

where RR<sub>MIN</sub> and RR<sub>MAX</sub> are constants; specifically, minimum and maximum distance squared to the sphere center.

I recommend using doubled coordinates for general cases. This allows you to select whether the center of the sphere is centered at a coordinate (implying odd diameter), or centered between two adjacent cordinates (implying even diameter).

If you have a `SIZE`×`SIZE`×`SIZE` grid of voxels (lights, building blocks, whatever), then

```
int sphere_surface(const char x, const char y, const char z,
                   const char size, const int rrmin, const int rrmax)
{
    const int center = size - (size & 1); /* Size rounded down to even integer */
    const int dx = center - x - x,
              dy = center - y - y,
              dz = center - z - z;        /* Doubled coordinates */
    const int rr = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz; /* Distance squared */
    return (rrmin <= rr) && (rr <= rrmax);
}
```

returns 1 if point (`x`,`y`,`z`) is within the surface region of the sphere centered in the cube. (Technically, it returns if the distance from that point to the center of the `size`-sized cube is within `sqrt(rrmin)/2` and `sqrt(rrmax)/2`, inclusive.)

The "correct" values of `rrmin` and `rrmax` are highly context dependent. `rrmax` is typically somewhere near `size*size` (remember, the function uses doubled coordinates), with `rrmin` somewhat less.

For example, if you have a 3×3×3 grid, you only want the six center cells on each face to fulfill the condition; you can do that with `size=3`, `rrmin=1`, `rrmax=4`:

[image: size=3, rrmin=1, rrmax=4]

If you have a 4×4×4 grid, you want the four center cells on each face to fulfill the condition (so a total of 24 of the 64 cells are considered to be on the sphere surface); you can do that with `size=4`, `rrmin=11`, `rrmax=11`:

[image: size=4, rrmin=11, rrmax=11]

With a 5×5×5 grid, we get to the interesting side effects of the above algorithm.

`size=5`, `rrmin=8`, `rrmax=16` yields a very "angular" sphere, almost a cube standing on a corner:

[image: size=5, rrmin=8, rrmax=16]

`size=5`, `rrmin=12`, `rrmax=20` yields my favourite approximate sphere:

[image: size=5, rrmin=12, rrmax=20]

`size=5`, `rrmin=16`, `rrmax=24` yields a rounded cube (each face a 3×3 flat):

[image: size=5, rrmin=16, rrmax=24]

Obviously, using `rrmin=0` includes all inner cells, too, yielding a ball instead of just the surface of a sphere.

As the grid size increases, the more variants of each size sphere you can represent.

The above function is especially useful on microcontrollers, because you can simply loop through your lattice, updating the state at each point, as you wish. Furthermore, most microcontrollers are tight on memory, but have very fast (single-clock) addition, subtraction, and multiplication instructions. (Although a 16×16-bit multiplication with 32-bit result typically takes two or more instructions.)

A typical microcontroller does not have the ROM/flash capability to store enough interesting voxel patterns, and only a few have DMA capability from an SD card via SPI (so you could just load "frames" of voxel patterns from a microSD card), but functions like the above can produce interesting shapes with few inputs -- and particularly inputs you can interpolate.

The above function can also be adapted for approximated antialising (by comparing `rr` to `rrmin` and `rrmax`), in case your voxels are not just binary, but e.g. PWM-controlled LEDs.

---

Since visualizing the above is typically a bit difficult, here is the quick little hack that I used to generate the above images. It outputs an SVG image to standard output, and ASCII slices to standard error, when given `size`, `rrmin`, and `rrmax` as command-line parameters.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define   BORDER  2
#define   XC(x,y,z) ((x)*16 + (y)*12)
#define   YC(x,y,z) ((x)*6 - (y)*8 - (z)*17)

static int xt = 0;
static int yt = 0;

static void fcube(FILE *out, const int x, const int y, const int z, const int fill)
{
    const int xc = xt + XC(x,y,z);
    const int yc = yt + YC(x,y,z);
    fprintf(out, "<path d=\"M%d,%dl16,6,12,-8,0,-17,-16,-6,-12,8z\" fill=\"#%06x\" stroke=\"#000\" />\n", xc, yc, fill & 0xFFFFFF);
    fprintf(out, "<path d=\"M%d,%dl16,6,12,-8m-12,8l0,17\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#000\" />\n", xc, yc-17);
}

static unsigned long rrmin = 0UL;
static unsigned long rrmax = 0UL;
static int           center = 0;

static int surface(const int x, const int y, const int z)
{
    /* Doubled coordinates: */
    const long dx = 2*x - center,
               dy = 2*y - center,
               dz = 2*z - center;
    const unsigned long rr = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz;

    return (rrmin <= rr) && (rr <= rrmax);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int  width, height;
    int  size, x, y, z;
    char dummy;

    if (argc != 4 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s SIZE RRMIN RRMAX\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "Where\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       SIZE    is the size of the voxel cube\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       RRMIN   is the minimum distance squared, and\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       RRMAX   is the maximum distance squared,\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "               using doubled coordinates.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Examples:\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s 3 1 4\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s 4 11 11\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s 5 8 16\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s 5 12 20\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s 5 16 24\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[1], " %d %c", &size, &dummy) != 1 || size < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid size.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[2], " %lu %c", &rrmin, &dummy) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid rrmin.\n", argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (sscanf(argv[3], " %lu %c", &rrmax, &dummy) != 1 || rrmax < rrmin) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid rrmax.\n", argv[3]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Calculate coordinate range. */
    {   int xmin = XC(0,0,0);
        int ymin = YC(0,0,0);
        int xmax = XC(0,0,0);
        int ymax = YC(0,0,0);

        for (z = 0; z <= size; z++)
            for (y = 0; y <= size; y++)
                for (x = 0; x <= size; x++) {
                    const int xc = XC(x,y,z);
                    const int yc = YC(x,y,z);
                    if (xc < xmin) xmin = xc;
                    if (xc > xmax) xmax = xc;
                    if (yc < ymin) ymin = yc;
                    if (yc > ymax) ymax = yc;
                } 

        xt = BORDER - xmin;
        width = xmax - xmin + 2*BORDER;

        yt = BORDER - ymin;
        height = ymax - ymin + 2*BORDER;
    }

    center = size - 1;

    /* SVG preamble. */
    printf("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n");
    printf("<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 %d %d\">\n", width, height);
    printf("<path d=\"M%d,%dL%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%dz\" fill=\"#f7f7f7\" stroke=\"#666666\"/>\n",
            xt+XC(   0,   0,   0), yt+YC(   0,   0,   0),
            xt+XC(size,   0,   0), yt+YC(size,   0,   0),
            xt+XC(size,size,   0), yt+YC(size,size,   0),
            xt+XC(size,size,size), yt+YC(size,size,size),
            xt+XC(0,   size,size), yt+YC(   0,size,size),
            xt+XC(0,      0,size), yt+YC(   0,   0,size));
    printf("<path d=\"M%d,%dL%d,%d,%d,%dM%d,%dL%d,%d\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#666666\"/>\n",
            xt+XC(   0,   0,   0), yt+YC(   0,   0,   0),
            xt+XC(   0,size,   0), yt+YC(   0,size,   0),
            xt+XC(size,size,   0), yt+YC(size,size,   0),
            xt+XC(   0,size,   0), yt+YC(   0,size,   0),
            xt+XC(   0,size,size), yt+YC(   0,size,size));
    for (z = 0; z < size; z++)
        for (y = size - 1; y >= 0; y--)
            for (x = 0; x < size; x++)
                if (surface(x,y,z))
                    fcube(stdout, x, y, z, 0x00CCFF);
    printf("</svg>\n");

    for (z=0; z < size; z++) {
        for (y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < size; x++)
                fputc(surface(x,y,z) ? 'X' : '.', stderr);
            fputs("   ", stderr);
            for (x = 0; x < size; x++)
                fputc(surface(x,z,y) ? 'X' : '.', stderr);
            fputs("   ", stderr);
            for (x = 0; x < size; x++)
                fputc(surface(y,z,x) ? 'X' : '.', stderr);
            fputc('\n', stderr);
        }
        fputc('\n', stderr);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I didn't bother to finesse the output; you can quite easily e.g. choose different colors for each face, maybe add shadows to the background planes, et cetera.

The above images were created with this program, then converted to PNG using GIMP, but I recommend using your browser to view the generated files locally.

Questions?

Answer (score -2):

the most common library used in this field is openGL 
and this slide show you how to configure the library on your IDE download the files from here 
http://www.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html
then put them in this paths
glut32.dll -> C:\Windows\System32
glut32.lib -> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET\Vc7\PlatformSDK\lib
glut.h -> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET\Vc7\PlatformSDK\Include\gl

opengl-superbible-4th this  a text book amazing one start from scratch to the advanced level

Comment: -1 From the question: *I can't use any OpenGL libraries*

Answer (score -3):

> I can't use any OpenGL libraries, I need vanilla C/C++ solution.

Does that mean no graphics libraries at all? In that case, the very simple answer is: you don't. Neither C nor C++ has native graphics-rendering abilites. you *need* to use an external library and driver just to get in touch with the OS' frame-buffer and/or graphics card.

However, as for my non-graphics related solution, it depends:

> I found Bresenham's circle algorithm but it's for 2D drawing. I just need spheres borders.

Does this mean you *literally* just need the sphere's borders? Because in that case, you should just use the 2d drawing algorithm you already have, since it gives you the borders right then and there.

If it means you want the individual voxels of the sphere, it's a little more complicated and is going to need a little more math, and possibly to the extent where a software renderer is just going to get punched in the face in terms of performance, depending on how many voxels and individual vertices your sphere has.

What I think you're trying to get is what game and physics-engine developers call a "bounding-box" or "collision-box", sometimes referred to as just "hitbox". All that requires is drawing a cube (usually wireframe) that encloses the entirety of the sphere and nothing more (In other words, you just draw a cube with the same width, height, and depth as the sphere, assuming we're working with an X-Y-Z dimension).

Comment: I fail to see how antagonizing someone for failing to word their thoughts perfectly enough for you achieves anything productive.