# Getting all pixels from a 3d image whithin a sphere

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

Given the sphere center coordinates and radius and the image in 3D how to get all pixels within the sphere using numpy in python ?
Assuming for the 3D image we have `indicesX, indicesY, indicesZ` arrays containing the pixels coordinates over X,Y and Z axis, `centerX, centerY, centerZ` contains the coordinates of center for the sphere and `r` is the radius.

Comment: Is `centerX`, `centerY`, and `centerZ` in pixel coordinates?

Comment: What is the shape of indicesX, indicesY and indicesZ ? Also what is the order of indices in your 3d image ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656006/how-to-rasterize-a-sphere/41666156#41666156

Comment: @RoySmart yes, they are in pixels

Comment: @MSS all are the same, each of them is (255, 255, 170)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do this is to construct a boolean mask using the equation for a sphere

```py
mask = (np.square(indicesX - centerX) + np.square(indicesY - centerY) + np.square(indicesZ - centerZ)) <= np.square(r)

indicesX_in_sphere = indicesX[mask]
indicesY_in_sphere = indicesY[mask]
indicesZ_in_sphere = indicesZ[mask]
```

or you could use the mask directly on the values of the 3D image depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have one more question, what you mena by using the mask directly on the values of the 3D image ?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this 3D image, but say you wanted to sum up all the pixels in the image, for example. You could do `np.sum(image[mask])` instead of `np.sum(image[indicesX_in_sphere, indicesY_in_sphere, indicesZ_in_sphere])`.

Comment: Thank you, in the end I need to calculate the median of the intensity of all pixels within the sphere

Comment: Is it correct to do like this ? `np.median(image[mask] > t)` if I need the median of all pixels with the intensity greater than a value `t` ?

Comment: You need to create a new mask and use [logical and](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) with the original mask to isolate that quantity. `np.median(image[mask & (image > t)])`

Comment: I understand, now it is clear to me. Thank you very very much!