# [draw]; Drawing 3d spheres

Tags: 3d, draw

I have a file which contains in each column x-coordinate, y-coordinate, z-coordinate and the radii of each sphere (I have thousands of spheres) and I would like to visualize them with any program, but I don't know which one I could use. Any help? If it is possible doing with C++ it would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can check out this post for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057471/drawing-3d-sphere-in-c-c

Answer (score 0):

ParaView is a good option. You only need a file with x,y,z,r coordinates. First apply the "table to points" filter and then the "glyph" filter. Is quite easy.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.