# Iterate Through Voxels in Spherical Volume from Center Out

Tags: java, math, iteration, spherical-coordinate

I'm not quite sure the best way to articulate this question, but I am trying to find a relatively simple way programmatically (in Java ideally, though theory is welcome too) to iterate through voxels one at a time starting from a center point and radiating out spherically. The idea is that I can specify a final radius (r) and starting coordinate <x, y, z> and at any given point in the process, the code will have iterated through each point within a radius that grows from 0 to r over the course of the function.

To be clear, I know how to search every coordinate in a spherical volume using spherical coordinates, but I don't know how to do it in the right order (starting from the center and moving outward.) Also, because it's voxels, I don't want to waste a bunch of time rounding iterations in the center just so the resolution can be complete on the outer surface. Ideally, each iteration should cover a new voxel and each voxel should be iterated exactly once (although I am open to compromise if that isn't possible).

Thanks for your help, let me know if I need to specify any further.

Comment: doing this with concentric squares is easy, but concentric spheres are problem because if you render voxelized sphere of radius `r` and `r+1` they will most likely share some voxels (that have distances between `r` and `r+1` from center ... so iterating through radius is a problem as with increasing `r` the step will be finer and finer (much less then 1) so how to handle that? You might compute all the combinations of integer coordinate distances between `r` and `r+1` ... now how to deal with continuity of points between neighboring spheres ? zig zag order of layers? what patter you aim for?

Comment: however putting all this together will be probably really slooooow without "huge" LUTs ... You might also round down or up the radiuses to ease up a bit however that would lead to holes in spheres which is not known if desired?

Comment: I actually don't mind the overlap between shells as much because including those would be less of a waste of processing than trying to eliminate them. If I'm fine with the overlap, how would I iterate each spherical shell?

Comment: for example similar to [Drawing 3D sphere in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135125/2521214) you just iterate in single direction in order: `r = <0,???>, x=<-r,+r>, y=<-r,+r>` and compute `z = sqrt(r*r-x*x-y*y)` or discard if `x*x+y*y>r*r` and for each surface voxel `x,y,z` emit voxels `x,y,z` and `x,y,-z`   spherical coordinates would just slow and mess things (in higher radiuses due rounding) up if you want to consequent voxels to be neighboring each other then just iterate in zig-zag pattern. If youre interested in such approach comment me and I would bust up something simple in C++

Comment: you need only to handle the edge case once you hit near circumference of XY plane circle where might be more voxels in the same line instead of just `x,y,+z` and `x,y,-z` detecting such case need some more thinking but the output is just line between those two points (so one for loop through `z`)

Answer (score 0):

This is an application for a [**priority queue**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) with (squared) radius as the priority.  Initialize it with the pair (0,(0,0,0)) and then, when dequeuing an element, consider each of its 3 neighbors with exactly one coordinate increased by 1.  For each of those, compute its squared radius and insert it into the queue if that is no greater than *r*<sup>2</sup>.  Some neighbor of some visited point must have the next smallest radius, so every point will be visited in order.

By symmetry, you can emit (±_i_,±_j_,±_k_) every time you dequeue a point (producing 1, 2, 4, or 8 values depending on how many coordinates are 0); you can also add (*x*,*y*,*z*) then.  If you want to be even more sophisticated, you can require that *i_≥_j_≥_k* as you generate points and then additionally **permute** them on output, producing 48 points from (3,2,1).

If you break radius ties with the coordinates themselves, remembering the last value emitted is sufficient to discard **duplicates** even for multiple points with the same radius like (6,5,1) and (7,3,2).  Each point is generated at most 3 times, so the number of duplicates is not excessive.